# How to make an attempt for only 3 times. In my case, when staff got 3 fail attempts(staff id) it would go back to the main screen

Tags: java

I am doing voting system for an assignment, 5 classes, votingInterface, votingController, staff, admin, candidates and 3 file.txt (admin, staff, candidate). What I need to do is to modify the code, and allow the staff to enter a password to get voted (which I did) but messy too.  If staff fail 3 attempts of staff id, it would go back to the screen.  You can see pretty much in this method below. I am new to Java and I need help, please.

```
public void manageVote()
{
    boolean moveOn = false;
    while (moveOn == false)
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter your staff ID :");  
        String input = getInput();

        theStaff = vc.getStaff(Integer.parseInt(input));

        if (theStaff != null)
        {        
            String pass = null; 
            System.out.print("Enter your password");
            pass=getInput().trim();

            if((theStaff.getPass()).equals(pass))
            { 
                getStaffVote();
                //moveOn=true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Incorrect username/password.");
            }
            try
            {
                if(theStaff.hasVoted() == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("\nYou have voted and cannot vote again\nGood bye...!");
                    moveOn = true;
                }   
                else if (theStaff.hasVoted() == 0)
                {
                    getStaffVote();
                    moveOn = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("There seems to be a problem.  Contact your administrator");
                }
            }     
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid entry - you must enter a number\nPlease try again");
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error! Staff ID not found.\nPress ENTER to try again or  \"q\" to QUIT :  " );
                if ("q".equalsIgnoreCase(getInput()))
                {
                    System.out.println("Good bye!");
                    moveOn = true;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.print("going back to voting screen...");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use another while loop comparing a integer counter which would increment after every wrong password entry.

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust your code to look like this:

```
// ...

do{
    System.out.print("Please enter your staff ID :");  
    String input = getInput();
    theStaff = vc.getStaff(Integer.parseInt(input));

    if(theStaff == null)
        System.out.print("No staff with that ID.");

}while(theStaff == null);

boolean isStaffAuthenticated = authenicateUser(theStaff, 3);

if(isStaffAuthenticated){
    // Do your logic for when a user is valid staff
    doStaffStuff(); 
}else{
    System.out.print("going back to voting screen...");
}

// ...
```

Where the authenicateUser method looks like this(please notice that I presumed the class name of your Staff object):

```
public boolean authenicateUser(Staff theStaff, int allowedTries){
int numberOfTries = allowedTries;
    do{
        String pass = null; 
        System.out.print("Enter your password");
        pass=getInput().trim();

        boolean isPassCorrect = (theStaff.getPass()).equals(pass);

        if(!isPassCorrect)
            System.out.println("Incorrect username/password.");

    }while(--numberOfTries > 0 && !isPassCorrect);

    return isPassCorrect;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, So I did what you suggest, but the problem is the Staff Id doesnt check the staff Id in file.txt(Staff.txt). It gives me "no staff with that id". I'll post it up what I've done.

Comment: If you are referring to functionality of your `getStaf(int id)` method, that seems to be out of scope of this question. You should search for "reading integers from a file"

Comment: I see you opened a new question. Can you give feedback does this answer help with the topic of this question?

Comment: well the problem is, it doesnt read the staff id stored in a Staff.txt file. It keeps saying "No staff with that Id". I do think the problem comes from here:  System.out.print("Please enter your staff ID :");  
    String input = getInput(); 
    theStaff = vc.getStaff(Integer.parseInt(input)); //Staff id is an integer..so this code is not reading or checking the id.

Comment: The problem seems to be in your  Voting Controllers `getStaff()` method, or even your `getInput()` method, both of which are not displayed here and are not even relevant to this question. Either way, how can you expect any more help from this place when you treat help that has been given like his?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your help, really appreciate it. So here is the solution for my question above. I did manage to ask my tutor after the assignment due, and heres what she recommended. Just want to post this up. Cheers

public void manageVote()

```
{
    boolean moveOn = false;
    boolean CheckStaffID = false;
    int wrongcheck = 1;
    //loop for each voter
    while (moveOn == false)
    {
     try{ 
         while(!CheckStaffID)
        {
            if(wrongcheck>3)
            {
                start();
                break;//to counter how much times wrong staff id is entered, more than 3 times, back to main screen
            }
            System.out.print("Please enter your staff ID :");

            theStaff = vc.getStaff(Integer.parseInt(getInput()));

            if(theStaff!=null)              
            {
              CheckStaffID = true;//find correct staff, stop loop
            }

            else
            {
              System.out.println("Incorrect staff ID");
              wrongcheck++;//display error message
            }

        }           
       System.out.print("Please enter your Password: ");


        if(theStaff.getPass().equals(getInput()))               
         {
              if(theStaff.hasVoted() == 1)
              {
                System.out.println("\nYou have voted and cannot vote again\nGood bye...!");
                moveOn = true;
              }
              else if (theStaff.hasVoted() == 0)
              {
                getStaffVote();
                moveOn = true;
              }
              else
              {
                System.out.println("There seems to be a problem.  Contact your administrator");
              }
         }                          
        else
          {
           System.out.println("Incorrect Password.");//password error message display
           CheckStaffID = false;//to re-enter staff logging system
          }

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {
             System.out.println("Invalid entry - you must enter a number\nPlease try again");
        }
        /*catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
              System.out.println("Error! Staff ID not found.\nPress ENTER to try again or  \"q\" to QUIT :  ");
                 if ("q".equalsIgnoreCase(getInput()))
                 {
                     System.out.println("Good bye!");
                     moveOn = true;
                 }
         }*///already have else to catch error, so comment this code
     }
     System.out.print("going back to voting screen...");
 }
```